# Scala - How to access nested columns in a dataframe?

Tags: scala, nested, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe 'df' with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- batch_key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- company_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- users_info: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- last_name: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- total_amount: double (nullable = true)
```

The column users_info is an array containing multiple structs.

I would like to change the column names such that 'batch_key' becomes 'batchKey', 'users_info' becomes 'usersInfo', 'first_name' becomes 'firstName' and etc.

I started with this code:

```
df2 = df
regex = new Regex("_(.)")
for (col <- df.columns) {
      df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed(col, regex.replaceAllIn(col, { M => M.group(1).toUpperCase }))
    }
```

But this code will only change the names of columns batch_key, company_id and users_info since `for (col <- df.columns)` returns `[batch_key, company_id, users_info]`.

The nested columns under users_info are not changed. How can I modify the above code such that I can access the nested columns and change their column names as well?

Comment: Probably you can use the [`select`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@select(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) method and do the same for the returned DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

In words: Create a `Seq` consisting of the flattened schema. Then use `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col` and create a `Seq` of `col({old column name}).as({new column name})` where you can use your regex for the new column name. Then use select to select the all columns from df but using the new names by calling `df.select({the seq of cols})`.

In more details:

Using the solution given here [Automatically and Elegantly flatten DataFrame in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471346/automatically-and-elegantly-flatten-dataframe-in-spark-sql) you can first flatten your schema and put it into a `Seq`

```
def fullFlattenSchema(schema: StructType): Seq[String] = {
  def helper(schema: StructType, prefix: String): Seq[String] = {
    val fullName: String => String = name => {if (prefix.isEmpty) name else s"$prefix.$name"}
    schema.fields.flatMap {
      case StructField(name, inner: StructType, _, _) => helper(inner, fullName(name))
      case StructField(name, _, _, _) => Seq(fullName(name))
    }
  }

  helper(schema, "")
}
```

Then you apply your Regex on the so obtained `Seq`

```
val renamed_columns = fullFlattenSchema(df.schema).map(c =>col(c).as(regex.replaceAllIn(c, { M => M.group(1).toUpperCase })));
```

Finally you select your dataframe using the renamed columns and check if the Schema is as you whish

```
val df2 = df.select(renamed_columns:_*);
df2.printSchema()
```