# How to extract data after mapped DataFrame in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm new to Spark and I'm trying to make a sense of how it works.
I'm trying to create a table(DataFrame) which has the column based on the json file I read.
What I've done is :

```
val example = mysession.read.json("/FileStore/tables/bm2982090/exampleLog_dp_api-fac53.json")
```

As the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) says, this returns a DataFrame. Now the DataFrame looks like this :

```
--------------------+-----------------+------+--------------------+-----+
|                 _id|           _index|_score|             _source|_type|
+--------------------+-----------------+------+--------------------+-----+
|AVzO9dqvoaL5S78GvkQU|dp_api-2017.06.22|     1|[2017-06-22T08:40...|DPAPI|
+--------------------+-----------------+------+--------------------+-----+
```

and as you can see, is doing a good job creating the column `_id, index` etc BUT when it comes to `_source` is putting everything inside and this happened because the file I've red looks like this:

```
{
  "_index":"dp_api-2017.06.22",
  "_type":"DPAPI",
  "_id":"AVzO9dqvoaL5S78GvkQU",
  "_score":1,
  "_source":{
    "request":{
      "user_ip":"ip",
      "method":"POST",
      "user_agent":"agent",
      "ts":"2017-06-22T10:40:37.420651+02:00"
    },
    "svc":"example",
    "cipher_info":{
      "userdata":[
        "field:parameters.username,start:0,end:0"
      ]
    },
    "message":"{\"class\":\"DPAPI\",\"event\":\"druid.auth.login\",\"operation\":{\"result\":{\"code\":200,\"description\":\"Success\",\"http_status\":200}},\"parameters\":,\"request\":{\"app_instance\":\"e83f99ff-a768-44d2-a448-9b51a535183f-1498034708\",\"end_point\":\"/oken\",\"method\":\"POST\",\"ts\":\"2017-06-22T10:40:37.420651+02:00\",\"user_agent\":\"Dr.1/Sa-SM-N\"},\"svc\":\"c-1\",\"ts\":\"2017-06-22T10:40:37.420614+02:00\"}",
    "type":"DPAPI",
    "tags":[
      "parse_to_json"
    ],
    "index_name":"dp_api",
    "class":"DPAPI",
    "operation":{
      "result":{
        "code":200,
        "description":"Success",
        "http_status":200
      }
    },
    "parameters":{
      "username":"Xp3opAyI0udKPuSQq5gqkQ=="
    },
    "event_age":0.37999987602233887,
    "ts":"2017-06-22T10:40:37.420614+02:00"
  }
}
```

so what I think is that when it comes to nested value then the process is "lazy" and it doesn't create the column correctly. My question is: Is it possible to extract the content of `_source` before creating the DataFrame? Or doing it after the dataframe is created, is fine but the output should look like that I have a table which has as many column as the keys.
For example :

```
--------------------+-----------------+------+--------------------+-----+
|                 _id|           _index|_score| _source.request.user_ip|_type|
+--------------------+-----------------+------+--------------------+-----+
|AVzO9dqvoaL5S78GvkQU|dp_api-2017.06.22|     1|ip              |DPAPI|
+--------------------+-----------------+------+--------------------+-----+
```

hope I explained well! thanks

Comment: use `example.printSchema`. You'll be able to see the fields clearly.

Comment: I think this answer should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/37473765/4390959

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess extracting after you create `dataframe` should be efficient and faster than extracting before you create a `dataframe`.

You have used `inbuilt functions` and `APIs` for creating `dataframe` from json. If you extract before that, then you will have to write some custom `APIs` yourself which won't be as efficient as the provided `APIs`.

You can just `select` the `columns` you require after the `dataframe` is created as below

```
example.select("_id", "_index", "_score", "_source.request.user_ip", "_type").show(false)
```

Which should give you the `dataframe` as you require

```
+--------------------+-----------------+------+-------+-----+
|_id                 |_index           |_score|user_ip|_type|
+--------------------+-----------------+------+-------+-----+
|AVzO9dqvoaL5S78GvkQU|dp_api-2017.06.22|1     |ip     |DPAPI|
+--------------------+-----------------+------+-------+-----+
```

I hope I answered your query well.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you :) thanks for the upvote and acceptance