# Flatten Spark JSON Data Frame with nested children attributes having the same names

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, flatten

Being a noob in Scala / Spark, am a bit stuck and would appreciate any help!

Am importing JSON data into a Spark Data Frame. In the process, I end up getting a Data frame having the same nested structure present in the JSON input.

My aim is to **flatten the entire Data Frame recursively (including the inner most child attributes in an array / dictionary), using Scala.**

Additionally, there may be children attributes which have the same names. Hence, need to differentiate them as well.

A somewhat similar solution (same child attributes for different parents) is shown here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38460312/3228300

An example of what I am hoping to achieve is as follows:

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}
```

The corresponding flattened output Spark DF structure would be:

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters_batter_id_0": "1001", 
    "batters_batter_type_0": "Regular",
    "batters_batter_id_1": "1002", 
    "batters_batter_type_1": "Chocolate",
    "batters_batter_id_2": "1003", 
    "batters_batter_type_2": "Blueberry",
    "batters_batter_id_3": "1004", 
    "batters_batter_type_3": "Devil's Food",
    "topping_id_0": "5001",
    "topping_type_0": "None",
    "topping_id_1": "5002", 
    "topping_type_1": "Glazed",
    "topping_id_2": "5005", 
    "topping_type_2": "Sugar",
    "topping_id_3": "5007", 
    "topping_type_3": "Powdered Sugar",
    "topping_id_4": "5006", 
    "topping_type_4": "Chocolate with Sprinkles",
    "topping_id_5": "5003", 
    "topping_type_5": "Chocolate",
    "topping_id_6": "5004", 
    "topping_type_6": "Maple"
}
```

Not having worked much with Scala and Spark previously, am unsure how to proceed.

Lastly, would be extremely thankful if someone can **please help with the code for a general / non-schema solution** as I need to be applying it to a lot of different collections.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility we approach it in one of our project

1. List item

define a case class that maps a row from the dataframe

```
case class BattersTopics(id: String, type: String, ..., batters_batter_id_0: String, ..., topping_id_0: String)
```

2. List item

map each row from the dataframe to case class

```
df.map(row => BattersTopics(id = row.getAs[String]("id"), ..., 
   batters_batter_id_0 = row.getAs[String]("batters_batter_id_0 "), ...)
```

Collect to a list and make a Map[String, Any] from the dataframe

```
val rows = dataSet.collect().toList
rows.map(bt => Map (
 "id" -> bt.id,
 "type" -> bt.type, 
 "batters" -> Map(
    "batter" -> List(Map("id" -> bt.batters_batter_id_0, "type" -> 
       bt.batters_batter_type_0), ....) // same for the others id and types
    "topping" -> List(Map("id"-> bt.topping_id_0, "type" -> bt.topping_type_0), ...) // same for the others id and type
  ) 
))
```

3. Use Jackson to convert the Map[String, Any] to Json

Comment: Hi @dumitru,

Firstly, thanks for helping out :)
From what I see, you have generated the mapping for the existing schema to the output schema.
However, my JSON file might have some additional dictionary elements from what I might currently consider (generated dynamically). Hence, need code for flattening recursively on unknown schema.
e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37473765/3228300
However, need to consider child attr. with same names as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data : which contains All different types of JSON element (Nested JSON Map, JSON Array, long, String etc..)

```
{"name":"Akash","age":16,"watches":{"name":"Apple","models":["Apple Watch Series 5","Apple Watch Nike"]},"phones":[{"name":"Apple","models":["iphone X","iphone XR","iphone XS","iphone 11","iphone 11 Pro"]},{"name":"Samsung","models":["Galaxy Note10","Galaxy S10e","Galaxy S10"]},{"name":"Google","models":["Pixel 3","Pixel 3a"]}]}
```

```
root
|— age: long (nullable = true)
| — name: string (nullable = true)
| — phones: array (nullable = true)
| | — element: struct (containsNull = true)
| | | — models: array (nullable = true)
| | | | — element: string (containsNull = true)
| | | — name: string (nullable = true)
| — watches: struct (nullable = true)
| | — models: array (nullable = true)
| | | — element: string (containsNull = true)
| | — name: string (nullable = true)
```

this is the sample data which have `arraytype` and `structtype` (Map) values in json Data.

We can use write first two switch conditions for each type and repeat this process unlit it flattens out to the required `Dataframe`.

https://medium.com/@ajpatel.bigdata/flatten-json-data-with-apache-spark-java-api-5f6a8e37596b

Here, is the Spark Java API solution.