# Flatten a DataFrame in Scala with different DataTypes inside

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, flatten

As you may know, a DataFrame can contain fields which are complex types, like structures (StructType) or arrays (ArrayType). You may need, as in my case, to map all the DataFrame data to a Hive table, with simple type fields (String, Integer...).
I've been struggling with this issue for a long time, and I've finally found a solution I want to share.
Also, I'm sure it could be improved, so feel free to reply with your own suggestions.

It's based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471346/automatically-and-elegantly-flatten-dataframe-in-spark-sql), but also works for ArrayType elements, not only StructType ones.
It is a tail recursive function which receives a DataFrame, and returns it flattened.

```
def flattenDf(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  var end = false
  var i = 0
  val fields = df.schema.fields
  val fieldNames = fields.map(f => f.name)
  val fieldsNumber = fields.length

  while (!end) {
    val field = fields(i)
    val fieldName = field.name

    field.dataType match {
      case st: StructType =>
        val childFieldNames = st.fieldNames.map(n => fieldName + "." + n)
        val newFieldNames = fieldNames.filter(_ != fieldName) ++ childFieldNames
        val newDf = df.selectExpr(newFieldNames: _*)
        return flattenDf(newDf)
      case at: ArrayType =>
        val fieldNamesExcludingArray = fieldNames.filter(_ != fieldName)
        val fieldNamesAndExplode = fieldNamesExcludingArray ++ Array(s"explode($fieldName) as a")
        val fieldNamesToSelect = fieldNamesExcludingArray ++ Array("a.*")
        val explodedDf = df.selectExpr(fieldNamesAndExplode: _*)
        val explodedAndSelectedDf = explodedDf.selectExpr(fieldNamesToSelect: _*)
        return flattenDf(explodedAndSelectedDf)
      case _ => Unit
    }

    i += 1
    end = i >= fieldsNumber
  }
  df
}
```

Comment: For starters, `val fieldNames = df.schema.fieldNames` :D

Comment: @RameshMaharjan try it out.. works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

val df = Seq(("1", (2, (3, 4)),Seq(1,2))).toDF()

**df.printSchema**

```
root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- _3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)


def flattenSchema(schema: StructType, fieldName: String = null) : Array[Column] = {
   schema.fields.flatMap(f => {
     val cols = if (fieldName == null) f.name else (fieldName + "." + f.name)
     f.dataType match {
       case structType: StructType => fattenSchema(structType, cols)
       case arrayType: ArrayType => Array(explode(col(cols)))
       case _ => Array(col(cols))
     }
   })
 }
```

**df.select(flattenSchema(df.schema) :_*).printSchema**

```
root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- _1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col: integer (nullable = false)
```