# renaming a Column in Data frame while flattening programatically Using selectExpr

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am using the the Code in Below link to flatten Nested Dataframe [Flatten a DataFrame in Scala with different DataTypes inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327647/flatten-a-dataframe-in-scala-with-different-datatypes-inside) .... I am getting the error below:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Reference 'alternateIdentificationQualifierCode' is ambiguous, could
>   be: alternateIdentificationQualifierCode#2,
>   alternateIdentificationQualifierCode#11.;
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:287)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:171)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$26.apply(Analyzer.scala:470)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$26.apply(Analyzer.scala:470)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$.withPosition(package.scala:48)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:470)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:466)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:335)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:335)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:334)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)

is there any way to Rename columns on the fly programatically in spark-dataframes in scala Thanks in Advance..
\

Code:

```
object flatten {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    if (args.length < 1) {
      System.err.println("Usage: XMLParser.jar <config.properties>")
      println("Please provide the Configuration File for the XML Parser Job")
      System.exit(1)
    }

    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark XML Process"))
    val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
    val prop = new Properties()
    prop.load(new FileInputStream(args(0)))
    val dfSchema = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag",prop.getProperty("xmltag")).load(prop.getProperty("input"))
    val flattened_DataFrame=flattenDf(dfSchema)

   // flattened_DataFrame.printSchema()

  }
```

Comment: have you tried withColumnRenamed api?

Comment: is there any examples can you provide which will be helpful and i ll just have to rename columns dynamically which keeps varying each time

Comment: are the number of columns fixed?

Comment: no.. if you actually look at the code in that link it iterates for each element in the array like this

Comment: val fields = df.schema.fields

Comment: while (!end) {
    val field = fields(i)

Comment: please look at the link above which may actually give you more clarity on whats my doubt

Comment: the link is about flattening a dataframe :) you want to rename all of the column names? your requirement is not clear actually.

Comment: can we see your code ?

Comment: Yes .. but i am uanble to post the code in comments

Comment: you can update the question :)

Comment: added the code as requested

Comment: so where are you getting the error then?

Comment: I am getting that error when the flatten method given in that link is invoked

Comment: because of same column names inside struct and normal fields in XML so i ll have to create an alias kind of thing for each column so the column names remain unique

Comment: Your dataframe must have ArrayType as dataType as the link given in question has problem with ArrayType. So to confirm please update your question with your dataframe schema before you flatten it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
val renamed_df = df.toDF(Seq("col1","col2","col3"))
```

to rename columns

Comment: I will not be knowing columns in advance, i am receiving a Dataframe Dynamically so in loop i ll have to rename the column on the fly with some naming convention

Comment: You can get column names as an array using "val colNames = df.columns". May be you can do something with that to find duplicates and rename those.

Comment: I will be knowing the column name only when flatening a struct