# Is this a valid Spark Schema?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema

I was in the process of flattening a Spark Schema using the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37473765/4513798), when I came across an edge case -

```
val writerSchema = StructType(Seq(
      StructField("f1", ArrayType(ArrayType(
        StructType(Seq(
          StructField("f2", ArrayType(LongType))
        ))
      )))
    ))

writerSchema.printTreeString()

root
 |-- f1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- f2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

This prints the following output - `f1` and not

```
f1
f1.f2
```

as I expected it to be.

Questions -

1. Is `writerSchema` a valid Spark schema?
2. How do I handle `ArrayType` objects when flattening the schema?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle data like this

```
val json = """{"f1": [{"f2": [1, 2, 3] }, {"f2": [4,5,6]}, {"f2": [7,8,9]}, {"f2": [10,11,12]}]}"""
```

The valid schema will be

```
val writerSchema = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("f1", ArrayType(
      StructType(Seq(
        StructField("f2", ArrayType(LongType))
      ))
    ))))

root
 |-- f1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- f2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

You shouldn't be putting an ArrayType inside another ArrayType.

So lets suppose you have a dataframe inputDF :

```
inputDF.printSchema
root
 |-- f1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- f2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)

inputDF.show(false)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|f1                                                                                                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[WrappedArray(1, 2, 3)], [WrappedArray(4, 5, 6)], [WrappedArray(7, 8, 9)], [WrappedArray(10, 11, 12)]]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

To flatten this dataframe we can explode the array columns (f1 and f2):

First, flatten column 'f1'

```
val semiFlattenDF = inputDF.select(explode(col("f1"))).select(col("col.*"))

semiFlattenDF.printSchema
root
 |-- f2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)

semiFlattenDF.show
+------------+
|          f2|
+------------+
|   [1, 2, 3]|
|   [4, 5, 6]|
|   [7, 8, 9]|
|[10, 11, 12]|
+------------+
```

Now flatten column 'f2' and get the column name as 'value'

```
val fullyFlattenDF = semiFlattenDF.select(explode(col("f2")).as("value"))
```

So now the DataFrame is flattened:

```
fullyFlattenDF.printSchema
root
 |-- value: long (nullable = true)

fullyFlattenDF.show
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
|    4|
|    5|
|    6|
|    7|
|    8|
|    9|
|   10|
|   11|
|   12|
+-----+
```