# How to flatten a nested field in a Spark Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have nested field like below. I want to call flatmap (I think) to produce a flattened row.

My dataset has

> A,B,[[x,y,z]],C

I want to convert it to produce output like

> A,B,X,Y,Z,C

This is for Spark 2.0+

Thanks!

Comment: http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2015/04/07/99-scala-problems-07-flatten/

Comment: can you share datatypes of your dataset?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache DataFu](http://datafu.apache.org/) has a generic [explodeArray](https://github.com/apache/datafu/blob/master/datafu-spark/src/main/scala/datafu/spark/SparkDFUtils.scala#L539) method that will do
exactly what you need.

```
import datafu.spark.DataFrameOps._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("A","B",Array("X","Y","Z"),"C"))).toDF
df.explodeArray(col("_3"), "token").show
```

This will produce:

```
+---+---+---------+---+------+------+------+
| _1| _2|       _3| _4|token0|token1|token2|
+---+---+---------+---+------+------+------+
|  A|  B|[X, Y, Z]|  C|     X|     Y|     Z|
+---+---+---------+---+------+------+------+
```

One thing to consider is that this method evaluates the data frame in order to determine how many columns to create - if it's expensive to compute it should be cached.

Full disclosure - I am a member of Apache DataFu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for RDD:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("A","B",Array("X","Y","Z"),"C")))

rdd.flatMap(x => (Option(x._3).map(y => (x._1,x._2,y(0),y(1),y(2),x._4 )))).collect.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(A,B,X,Y,Z,C)
```

Comment: It's very specific

Comment: may not be possible to be generic

Comment: Try this - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471346/automatically-and-elegantly-flatten-dataframe-in-spark-sql `

Comment: Provide more details on your data like schema!

Comment: Looked on SO. As soon as intermixing occurs seems problematic