# Flatten only deepest level in scala spark dataframe

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, flatten

I have a Spark job, which has a DataFrame with the following value :

```
{
  "id": "abchchd",
  "test_id": "ndsbsb",
  "props": {
    "type": {
      "isMale": true,
      "id": "dd",
      "mcc": 1234,
      "name": "Adam"
    }
  }
}

{
  "id": "abc",
  "test_id": "asf",
  "props": {
    "type2": {
      "isMale": true,
      "id": "dd",
      "mcc": 12134,
      "name": "Perth"
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to flatten it out elegantly (as no of keys is unknown and type etc) in such a way that props remains as a `struct` but everything inside it is flattened off (irrespective of the level of nesting)

The output desired is :

```
{
  "id": "abchchd",
  "test_id": "ndsbsb",
  "props": {
    "type.isMale": true,
    "type.id": "dd",
    "type.mcc": 1234,
    "type.name": "Adam"
  }
}

{
  "id": "abc",
  "test_id": "asf",
  "props": {
      "type2.isMale": true,
      "type2.id": "dd",
      "type2.mcc": 12134,
      "type2.name": "Perth"
  }
}
```

I used the solution mentioned in 
[Automatically and Elegantly flatten DataFrame in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471346/automatically-and-elegantly-flatten-dataframe-in-spark-sql)

however, I'm unable to keep the props field intact. It also gets flattened off. 
Can somebody help me with extending this solution?

The final schema should be something like :

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- props: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type.id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type.isMale: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type.mcc: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type.name: string (nullable = true)
      |-- type2.id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type2.isMale: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type2.mcc: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type2.name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test_id: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Hi @mythic, so all you know from your structure is that there may be some `props` field being an object, having attributes being sub-objects too, right ?

Comment: @baitmbarek thats correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been able to achieve this with the RDD API :

```
val jsonRDD = df.rdd.map{row =>
  def unnest(r: Row): Map[String, Any] = {
    r.schema.fields.zipWithIndex.flatMap{case (f, i) =>
      (f.name, f.dataType) match {
        case ("props", _:StructType) =>
          val propsObject = r.getAs[Row](f.name)
          Map(f.name -> propsObject.schema.fields.flatMap{propsAttr =>
            val subObject = propsObject.getAs[Row](propsAttr.name)
            subObject.schema.fields.map{subField =>
              s"${propsAttr.name}.${subField.name}" -> subObject.get(subObject.fieldIndex(subField.name))
            }
          }.toMap)
        case (fname, _: StructType) => Map(fname -> unnest(r.getAs[Row](fname)))
        case (fname, ArrayType(_: StructType,_)) => Map(fname -> r.getAs[Seq[Row]](fname).map(unnest))
        case _ => Map(f.name -> r.get(i))
      }
    }
  }.toMap

  val asMap = unnest(row)
  new ObjectMapper().registerModule(DefaultScalaModule).writeValueAsString(asMap)
}

val finalDF = spark.read.json(jsonRDD.toDS).cache
```

The solution should accept deeply nested inputs, thanks to recursion.

With your data, here's what we get :

```
finalDF.printSchema()
finalDF.show(false)
finalDF.select("props.*").show()
```

Outputs :

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- props: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type.id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type.isMale: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type.mcc: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type.name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test_id: string (nullable = true)

+-------+----------------------+-------+
|id     |props                 |test_id|
+-------+----------------------+-------+
|abchchd|[dd, true, 1234, Adam]|ndsbsb |
+-------+----------------------+-------+

+-------+-----------+--------+---------+
|type.id|type.isMale|type.mcc|type.name|
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+
|     dd|       true|    1234|     Adam|
+-------+-----------+--------+---------+
```

But we can also pass more nested/complexe structures like for instance :

```
val str2 = """{"newroot":[{"mystruct":{"id":"abchchd","test_id":"ndsbsb","props":{"type":{"isMale":true,"id":"dd","mcc":1234,"name":"Adam"}}}}]}"""

...

finalDF.printSchema()
finalDF.show(false)
```

Gives the following output :

```
root
 |-- newroot: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- mystruct: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- props: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type.id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type.isMale: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type.mcc: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type.name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- test_id: string (nullable = true)

+---------------------------------------------+
|root                                         |
+---------------------------------------------+
|[[[abchchd, [dd, true, 1234, Adam], ndsbsb]]]|
+---------------------------------------------+
```

**EDIT**: As you mentioned, if you have records with different structure you need to wrap the above `subObject` value in an option.
Here's the fixed `unnest` function :

```
def unnest(r: Row): Map[String, Any] = {
  r.schema.fields.zipWithIndex.flatMap{case (f, i) =>
    (f.name, f.dataType) match {
      case ("props", _:StructType) =>
        val propsObject = r.getAs[Row](f.name)
        Map(f.name -> propsObject.schema.fields.flatMap{propsAttr =>
          val subObjectOpt = Option(propsObject.getAs[Row](propsAttr.name))
          subObjectOpt.toSeq.flatMap{subObject => subObject.schema.fields.map{subField =>
            s"${propsAttr.name}.${subField.name}" -> subObject.get(subObject.fieldIndex(subField.name))
          }}
        }.toMap)
      case (fname, _: StructType) => Map(fname -> unnest(r.getAs[Row](fname)))
      case (fname, ArrayType(_: StructType,_)) => Map(fname -> r.getAs[Seq[Row]](fname).map(unnest))
      case _ => Map(f.name -> r.get(i))
    }
  }
}.toMap
```

New `printSchema` gives :

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- props: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type.id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type.isMale: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type.mcc: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type.name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type2.id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type2.isMale: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type2.mcc: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type2.name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test_id: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Hi @baitmbarek, This seems to work! Looks simple and powerful! Thank you so much. 

Just had a question, with respect to nested fields, 

if I do a 

     finalDf.select("props.type.id")

It throws an error saying the field was not found. This is because spark is looking for a strong struct called type and hence it fails. One work around is to rename the subfields to 

     type_id

and replace the dot with the underscore. Is there any other way that I could go ahead with dot without it being a struct field?

Comment: Hi @mythic you need to "escape" the dot : ```finalDF.select("props.`type.isMale`").show()```. This renders the `type.isMale` column

Comment: Hi @baitmbarek, this solution seems to be breaking when the df has different named fields. 
I have a field called "type" and also a field called "type1" in another row of the df. 

Its throwing a null pointer exception! :(

Comment: Hi @mythic can you share the structure so I can fix / adapt the method ?

Comment: Hi @baitmbarek, Ive added two rows from the dataframe and also the final desired schema. Please let me know if you require anything else

Comment: Thank you @mythic I'll take a look at it this evening ;)

Comment: @mythic I just edited the answer with an improvement to handle potentially missing attributes