# Is there a way to collect the names of all fields in a nested schema in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wish to collect the names of all the fields in a nested schema. The data were imported from a json file.

The schema looks like:

```
root
 |-- column_a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_b: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_c: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- nested_a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- double_nested_a: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- double_nested_b: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- double_nested_c: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- nested_b: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_d: string (nullable = true)
```

If I use `df.schema.fields` or `df.schema.names` it just prints the names of the column layer - none of the nested columns.

The desired output I want is a python list, which contains all the column names such as:

```
['column_a', 'columb_b', 'column_c.nested_a.double_nested.a', 'column_c.nested_a.double_nested.b', etc...]
```

The information exists there if I want to write a custom function - but am I missing a beat? Does there exist a method that achieves what I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default in Spark doesn't have any method to give us flatten the schema names.

Use the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50156142) post:

```
def flatten(schema, prefix=None):
    fields = []
    for field in schema.fields:
        name = prefix + '.' + field.name if prefix else field.name
        dtype = field.dataType
        if isinstance(dtype, ArrayType):
            dtype = dtype.elementType

        if isinstance(dtype, StructType):
            fields += flatten(dtype, prefix=name)
        else:
            fields.append(name)

    return fields


df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- column_a: string (nullable = true)
# |-- column_c: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- nested_a: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- double_nested_a: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- nested_b: string (nullable = true)
# |-- column_d: string (nullable = true)

sch=df.schema

print(flatten(sch))
#['column_a', 'column_c.nested_a.double_nested_a', 'column_c.nested_b', 'column_d']
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the schema contains arrays:

`|-- automatons: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- agentGroup: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- automatonAttribute: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- acif_version: string (nullable = true)`