# Check datatype of column using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Need some help on checking the data type in spark,

I need to convert this pyspark functionality in spark

```
if dict(df.dtypes)['test_col'] == 'String':
...     print "it is String type"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check data type of column, Use `schema` function.

Check below code.

```
df
.schema
.filter(c => c.name == "test_col") // Check your column
.map(_.dataType.typeName)
.headOption
.getOrElse(None)
```

```
val dtype = df
.schema
.filter(a => a.name == "c1")
.map(_.dataType.typeName)
.headOption
.getOrElse(None)

if (dtype == "string") println("it is String type")
```

Use `dtypes` function.

```
val dtype = df
.dtypes
.filter(_._1 == "c1")
.map(_._2)
.headOption
.getOrElse(None)

if (dtype  == "StringType" ) println("it is String type")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618715/is-there-a-way-to-collect-the-names-of-all-fields-in-a-nested-schema-in-pyspark) to include the datatype in the schema.

Just pass the schema of your dataframe to the function `flatten` and it will provide you column name and its datatype.

```
def flatten(schema, prefix=None):
    fields = []
    for field in schema.fields:
        name = prefix + '.' + field.name if prefix else field.name
        dtype = field.dataType
        if isinstance(dtype, ArrayType):
            dtype = dtype.elementType

        if isinstance(dtype, StructType):
            fields += flatten(dtype, prefix=name)
        else:
            fields.append((name, dtype))

    return fields

mySchema = flatten(df.schema)
print("Schema is here", mySchema)
```