# How to append multiple JSON schema values into a single column under a dataframe using Pyspark

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark

I have multiple source JSON files where each JSON file will have different schemas present in it.

For example below 3 Json files, I've presented it in a tabular view for better understanding, but I've also provided the schema as well:

Json File 1:

| Key | Value | Column_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `sample_column.pull.notify.roid.alert` | aaa | Column A |
| `sample_column.pull.notify.roid.title` | bbb | Column B |
| `sample_column.pull.notify.roid.action.pan.content` | ccc | Column C |

JSON File 1 Schema:

```
|-- sample_column: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- pull: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- notify: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- roid: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- action: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- pan: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- content: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- alert: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

Json File 2:

| Key | Value | Column_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `sample_column.cone.pull.notify.roid.alert` | a1a1a1 | Column A |
| `sample_column.cone.pull.notify.roid.title` | b1b1b1 | Column B |
| `sample_column.cone.pull.notify.roid.action.pan.content` | c1c1c1 | Column C |

JSON File 2 Schema:

```
|-- sample_column: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- cone: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- pull: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- notify: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- roid: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- action: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pan: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- content: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- alert: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

Json File 3:

| Key | Value | Column_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `sample_column.var.pull.notify.roid.alert` | a2a2a2 | Column A |
| `sample_column.var.pull.notify.roid.title` | b2b2b2 | Column B |
| `sample_column.var.pull.notify.roid.action.pan.content` | c2c2c2 | Column C |

JSON File 3 Schema:

```
|-- sample_column: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- var: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- pull: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- notify: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- roid: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- action: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pan: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- content: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- alert: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to get "alert", "title" and "content" from those 3 different schemas and put all the "Alert" values under Column A, then all the "Title" values under Column B and all the "Content" value under Column C

This will be the expected output Table:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb | ccc |
| a1a1a1 | b1b1b1 | c1c1c1 |
| a2a2a2 | b2b2b2 | c2c2c2 |

So, as the above scenario I tried to append all different schema like all ('**a**') values under column A then ('**b**') values under column B and ('**c**') values under column C but the values are getting overwritten like below:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a2a2a2 | b2b2b2 | c2c2c2 |

**Below is the Pyspark Code that I've tried which overwrites the values but not appending it:**

```
def has_column(df, col):
# Checks whether the dataframe has a column, if the dataframe has a column, returns True else False.
    try:
        df[col]
        return True
    except:
        return False

if has_column(df, "sample_column.pull.notify.roid.alert"):
     try:
         df = df.withColumn('Column A', when(df.sample_column.pull.notify.roid.alert.isNotNull(), df["sample_column.pull.notify.roid.alert"]))
     except:
         df = df.withColumn('Column A', lit("").cast("string"))

if has_column(df, "sample_column.cone.pull.notify.roid.title"):
     try:
         df = df.withColumn('Column A', when(df.sample_column.cone.pull.notify.roid.title.isNotNull(), df["sample_column.cone.pull.notify.roid.title"]))
     except:
         df = df.withColumn('Column A', lit("").cast("string"))

if has_column(df, "sample_column.var.pull.notify.roid.action.pan.content"):
     try:
         df = df.withColumn('Column A', when(df.sample_column.var.pull.notify.roid.action.pan.content.isNotNull(), df["sample_column.var.pull.notify.roid.action.pan.content"]))
     except:
         df = df.withColumn('Column A', lit("").cast("string"))
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: could you show `df.printSchema()`?  it is a little hard to understand whether you mean the key is the nested object or literally your key has "." in it.

Comment: It's a nested object. I just represented in that table format for a clear view... I'll update it with the schema as well

Comment: The Above 3 JSON values are read and kept under a df.

Comment: So, I need to get "alert", "title" and "content" from those 3 different schemas and put all the "Alert" values under Column A, then all the "Title" values under Column B and all the "Content" value under Column C.

Answer (score 0):

```
    data =[["aaa","bbb","ccc"],["a1a1a1","b1b1b1","c1c1c1"],["a2a2a2","b2b2b2","c2c2c2"]]
    columns = ["ColumnA","ColumnB","ColumnC"]
    df_in = spark.createDataFrame(data,columns)
    (
      df_in
        .agg(collect_list("ColumnA").alias("ColumnA"),
             collect_list("ColumnB").alias("ColumnB"),
             collect_list("ColumnC").alias("ColumnC"))
      .show(10, False)
    )
    # This result maybe what you wanted.
    #+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
    #|ColumnA              |ColumnB              |ColumnC              |
    #+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
    #|[aaa, a1a1a1, a2a2a2]|[bbb, b1b1b1, b2b2b2]|[ccc, c1c1c1, c2c2c2]|
    #+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: We have the resulting data under a list in a single row, but I need aaa in one row, a1a1a1 in another row and a2a2a2 in another row.

Comment: u can try "explode" like this: ur_df.withColumn("ColumnA", explode(col("ColumnA"))) . Schema: ColumnA: array.

Comment: pyspark.sql.functions.explode(col): Returns a new row for each element in the given array or map.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate them with `coalesce`.

First, set up what you want to extract.

```py
paths = ['sample_column.pull.notify.roid',
         'sample_column.cone.pull.notify.roid',
         'sample_column.var.pull.notify.roid']

extract_keys = ['alert', 'title', 'action.pan.content']
```

Then use [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html) to get value where it exists.

```py
df = (df.select(*[
          coalesce(*[col(f'{path}.{key}') for path in paths]).alias(key)
          for key in extract_keys
        ])
      .withColumnRenamed('action.pan.content', 'content')
)
```

**Explaination**

I used double list comprehension in above example but you can break this down.

This function;

```py
coalesce(*[col(f'{path}.title') for path in paths])
```

translates to

```py
coalesce('sample_column.pull.notify.roid.title',
         'sample_column.cone.pull.notify.roid.title',
         'sample_column.var.pull.notify.roid.title')
```

and this will return whichever has a (non-null) value  per row (row=1 JSON).

And I am doing this for all `extract_keys`, that is the outer list comprehension.

**Consideration**

I hardcoded the paths in this example. If you are curious to go beyond and figure out the `paths` without  hardcoding, you can probably look into [Is there a way to collect the names of all fields in a nested schema in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618715/is-there-a-way-to-collect-the-names-of-all-fields-in-a-nested-schema-in-pyspark) for some ideas.

Comment: Thank You for your response and opinions! I'll try this.